# Alt Key Binding Issues

Tags: macos, emacs, key-bindings

I am running OSX 10.7 and have currently configured my <kbd>Alt</kbd> to be the <kbd>A</kbd> key in emacs with:

```
(setq mac-option-modifier 'alt)
```

I can see this when I boot up emacs by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> for instance and see

```
A-k is not defined.
```

However, when I try to set a keybinding like

```
(global-set-key (kbd "A-k") 'magit-status)
```

The same chord is undefined. Please let me know if I am missing something to enable the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key or if you need more information.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

weird, I had an error in my key bindings file and the elisp compiler isn't forgiving (it messes with subsequent bindings)

if anyone is curious, I have my global keybindings [here](https://github.com/shicholas/dotfiles/blob/master/.emacs.d/shicholas/hooks/after-init.el)